# How can I add to my list a manual field

Tags: query

How can I add to my list a manual field (oName), because I want to add the object name of the query. In other sql I can use syntax below.

```
    SELECT Id, Name, createdDate, 'value' as oName FROM TASK



    if(wrapperList == null) {
        wrapperList = new List <wrapper>();
        
        for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate from Task limit 10]) {
            wrapperList.add(new wrapper(a));
        }
```

Comment: This is not possible in SOQL unfortunately. You could create a formula field on the task object with that literal value in it and add that field to the query. Its name will have to conform to Salesforce field name logic, so it'll not exactly be named `oName`, but `oName__c` at the very least :)

Comment: Ok or can I add an additional information in the ADD syntax like - wrapperList.add(new wrapper(a, 'Task'));

Comment: Sure, that could also work.

Comment: can you help me how does it work? if I add it like - wrapperList.add(new wrapper(a, String('Task'))); - error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void String(String) from the type DokuBox_4

Comment: You can simply use; `wrapperList.add(new wrapper(a, 'Task'));`, like you had in your ealier comment. Then you have to change the constructor (within the class itself) to something like `wrapper(Task tsk, String oName){....`